# Linearlayout weight works on android studio, doesn't on device

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

While making a simple items-layout for a Listview, I am having this problem:

This is how it looks on android studio (correct way)
[image: How it looks like in Android Studio]
This is how it looks on the device (w)
[image: How it looks on device]
It is like the weight is not working on the device!

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mp_imagen"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_background"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mp_titulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Título del producto"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#77000000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mp_imagen"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mp_imagen"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mp_imagen"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mp_imagen"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mp_imagen"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mp_interesados"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Interesados"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_interest"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mp_chats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Chats"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_chat"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also show how are you putting images for Interesados and Chats.

Comment: @Apurva it is right there (drawableleft)... i am not modifying anything programatically (yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LinearLayout as root and put only Image and textView above Image in RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:background="#FFFFFF" >

     <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/mp_imagen"
             android:layout_width="130dp"
             android:layout_height="130dp"
             ..../>

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/mp_titulo"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             ..../>
      </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mp_interesados"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Interesados"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_interest"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mp_chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Chats"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_chat"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OK this worked. But I'd really like to know why I need an extra layout??